# How to map keys in Genymotion?

Tags: genymotion

I am using Genymotion to play Android games on Linux. But I can not play some games, as they have special control layout.

Do you know how to add keyboard mapping feature to Genymotion, like in other Android emulators for Windows such as Nox, Memu, BlueStack?